# llevar valor de variable local a global

Tags: python, regex

Buenas estaba trabajando haciendo validaciones del dni utilizando regex para los numeros, pero queria quitar la letra aunque hay otras maneras más optimas para hacerlo, el caso que he creado una funcion donde manipulo una variable que estaba fuera de la función que es el caso del dni junto con la letra que viene todo en string y le digo en la funcion que si el último dígito de la variable dni es un numero que vuelva a escribirlo para que sea una letra y luego elimino la letra dejando sólo el numero pero claro al estar dentro de la función la variable dni no cambia fuera de la funcion que es lo que quiero que haga, vamos hacer que la variable dni se global una vez cambiada dentro de la función. y que cuando salga de la funcion la variable dni esté modificada para poder pasarle la validacion con regex.

```
import re
def p_l(dni):
    while dni[-1] in num:
        print ('tu dni debe tenr 8 dígitos numérico y una letra final')
        dni=input('Escribe tu dni: ')
        p_l(dni)
    dni=dni[:-1]#aquí es donde quiero que cambie la variable 
num='0123456789'
dni=input('Escribe tu dni: ')
p_l(dni)
#a partir de aqui me gustaria que dni tenga el valor que le ha dado la función
sub_cadena=re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d',dni)
try:
    if sub_cadena.group()==dni:
        print('correcto')
    else:
        print('El numero no es correcto')
except AttributeError:
    print('El número debe contener 8 dígitos')
```

Comment: No he entedido nada

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres compartir una variable global, la creas fuera de la función y dentro de ella la declaras `global` si la quieres modificar:

```
dni = None

def p_l():
    global dni
    dni = input("DNI?")

print(dni)
```

Sin embargo, las buenas prácticas desincentivan el uso de variables globales.

Reorganizando el código podemos evitar el uso de variables globales:

```
def p_l():
    dni = input('Escribe tu dni: ')
    while len(dni) != 8 and dni[-1] in '0123456789':
        print ('tu dni debe tenr 8 dígitos numérico y una letra final')
        dni=input('Escribe tu dni: ')
    return dni[:-1] #aquí es donde quiero que cambie la variable
```

Hemos simplificado la función `p_l`. No necesitamos recibir el `dni`, simplemente lo pedimos y validamos dentro de la función, y lo retornamos al llamante:

```
dni = p_l()
```

El resto del código queda igual:

#### Demo

```
import re

def p_l():
    dni = input('Escribe tu dni: ')
    while len(dni) != 8 and dni[-1] in '0123456789':
        print ('tu dni debe tenr 8 dígitos numérico y una letra final')
        dni=input('Escribe tu dni: ')
    return dni[:-1] #aquí es donde quiero que cambie la variable

dni = p_l()
#a partir de aqui me gustaria que dni tenga el valor que le ha dado la función
sub_cadena=re.search(r'\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d',dni)
try:
    if sub_cadena.group()==dni:
        print('correcto')
    else:
        print('El numero no es correcto')
except AttributeError:
    print('El número debe contener 8 dígitos')
```

produce:

```
Escribe tu dni: 123456789
tu dni debe tenr 8 dígitos numérico y una letra final
Escribe tu dni: 12345678h
correcto

Process finished with exit code 0
```